# Как сделать плавный transition для background-image при :hover

Tags: html, css, css-animation, scss

Помогите, пожалуйста, у меня есть блок на котором есть изначально залитый однородный цвет и при наведении должно плавно изменится на картинку. Я придумал вариант сначала на блок дать background-image c указанием `linear-gradient(rgb(235, 175, 174))` и тем самым я перекрываю картинку цветом, а при `:hover linear-gradient(rgba(235, 175, 174, 0))` становится нулевой и проявляется картинка (я подумал что это самое логичное решение, но не вышло..)

После этого я попробовал вариант с `transparent` и `background-color`. Я хотел добавить `background-image` на `<div>`, сделать его неподвижным чтобы с ним никаких манипуляций не производить, а сразу вместе с ним поставить `background-color`, а после `:hover` чтоб `background-color` становился полностью прозрачным и был бы норм результат, но `background-image` стоит выше в приоритете чем `background-color` и он перекрывает его.. Я потом ещё кое-что пробовал варианты кину ниже, помогите плиз.

```
.block1,  
.block2,  
.block3 {  
  display: block;  
  margin: auto;  
  width: 400px;  
  height: 250px;  
}

.block1 {  
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(rgb(235, 175, 174)), 
    url(../images.png);
  transition: background-image 550ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  
  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    background-image: 
      linear-gradient(rgb(235, 175, 174,0)),
      url(../images.png)
  }
}

.block2 {
  background-image: url(../images.png);
  background-color: rgb(235, 175, 174);
  transition: background-image 550ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);

  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    background-color: rgba(174, 118, 118, 0);
  }
}

.block3 {
  background-color: rgb(174, 118, 118);
  transition: background-color 550ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  
  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    background-image: url(../images/tutorial-page-html-css.png);
    background-color: rgba(174, 118, 118, 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Анимировать можно только измеряемые значения, а фон-картинка к таковым не относится.
Можно сделать дополнительный дочерний контейнер, засунуть в него картинку, спозиционировать сверху, сделать opacity: 0 и по наведению менять opacity на 1.

Анимация замены фонов при наведении(глючит в Chrome, может не запускаться в Firefox)

```css
.block {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  transition: background-image 1s ease;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/fsyrScY.jpg);
}
.block:hover {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/LQwng2m.jpeg')
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Ну если менять одну картинку на другую - то анимацию применить все таки можно.

Comment: Досадно, что разрабы сделали возможность использовать слои в `background-image`, но не додумались сделать какой-то `background-image-opacity` для этих слоёв..

Comment: вы можете при ховере менять картинку, но без анимации. Слишком сложная операция изменять прозрачность или цвета у каждого пикселя. А вот целиком, в рамках общего родительского блока opacity другое дело - это более тупая операция.

Comment: А вы пробовали? Я не уверен что можно сменить с цвета на картинку с анимацией, но изменить одну картинку на другую - можно.

Comment: да, действительно, проверила можно, в chrome, но оно немного подтупливает, в Firefox вообще не заработало.

Comment: Kjuri спасибо большое, всё получилось, вы супер))